# Rails table-less model or a better way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using *Rails 3.2.12*.

I have a model `A` and table called `a`. I need to tag in `a_details` which is a set of attributes based on type of `A`. There is *no* table for `a_details`. Its made on the fly. In the show method I'm calling a method `getAdetails` and in the response I am passing both as JSON objects, `A` and `A_details`.

This gets tricky in the `index` method as there is going to be many and I don't think I want to loop through each one to make an array object and render them through. I was thinking about table-less model and using a gem called `activerecord_association` using the `:include` method while rendering to JSON. I was thinking, is there a better way of doing this?

```
# show method.
a = A.new
@a_detail = @a.getADetails
response = {:notification => @a.as_json(:include => :creator), :a_detail => @a_detail}

#index
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @objects.as_json(:include => :creator) }
end
```

Comment: So, to narrow down the question --- you want to create JSON for an array of Ruby objects, right?

Comment: yes!! but in a better way and i want it to be a part of the object A itself. like how the creator will be with in object A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the :methods option?

```
render json: @objects.as_json(include:'creator', methods:'getADetails')
```

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Edited to return an array

Comment: This is will work for one object, can do this for a collection of objects in the index method.

Comment: Sure, edited it to return an array.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: But stil this does not solve the problem of calling the  getDetails on every single a object right?@a_detail = @a.getADetails

Comment: Fair enough, how about now?